# when $\gcd{(a, tm)}=1$, we have $\gcd{(a+btm, tm^2)}=1$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $m$ be an odd prime and $t$ is an integer.

When $\gcd{(a, tm)}=1$, $a < tm$, my question is that we have

$\gcd{(a+btm, tm^2)}=1$?

where $b$ is an integer such that $1 \leq b \leq m-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be prime, $p|\gcd{(a+btm, tm^2)}$. It follows from $p|tm^2$ that either $p=m$ or $p|t$.

Evidently, the first case is impossible. But if  $p|t$ then $p|(a+btm)$ implies $p|a$.